# AlertDialog to DialogFragment

Tags: android, dialog

OK the method showDialog(int, Bundle) from the type Activity is deprecated... So I have already changed my timePicker to fragmentDialog and it was pretty easy because fragmentDialog has prepared:

```
new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(),_listener, _hour, _minute,dateFormat);
```

But how can I remake to fragmentDialog my dialog of this type?

```
AlertDialog.Builder
        .setIcon()
        .setTitle()
        .setPositiveButton()
        .setSingleChoiceItems(new CharSequence[]{"Visual","Audio","Both"},2,null)
```

Thank you.

Comment: Could not understand: `how can I remake to fragmentDialog lots of my dialogs of this type with the same layout?` do you want to display an single choiced AlertDialog within DialogFragmnet?

Comment: I changed my question. Hope this is clearer.

Comment: It is still not clear. What i have understand that the you dont want to work with `showDialog` and you want to use `AlertDialog.Builder
        .setIcon()
        .setTitle()
        .setPositiveButton()
        .setSingleChoiceItems(new CharSequence[]{"Visual","Audio","Both"},2,null)` in the `DialogFragment`, Am i right?

Comment: Shajeel Afzal - yes you understand right.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly, you want to **reuse** your `AlerDialog` so you can define it once and use in different places in your fragment/activity.

From android Documentation `AlertDialog android.app.AlertDialog.Builder.create()` `Creates a AlertDialog with the arguments supplied to this builder. It does not show() the dialog. This allows the user to do any extra processing before displaying the dialog. Use show() if you don't have any other processing to do and want this to be created and displayed.`
So:

```
//declare inside your fragment class
private AlertDialog welcomeDialog;

//Inisde onCreate paste the following code so your dialoge is just created but not shown
            welcomeDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                .setTitle(
                        getResources().getString(R.string.first_run_title))
                .setMessage(
                        getResources().getString(R.string.first_run_desc))
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok,
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int which) {
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        }).create();

//Wherever in your code you need to display the dialog,just use this piece of code:
welcomeDialog.show();

//and finally to do the cleanup:
    @Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (welcomeDialog != null)
        welcomeDialog.dismiss();}
```

Comment: This person does not respond so i did'nt answered his question

Comment: pls do answer becose it might me helpful to me and the others

Comment: I didn't respond for something? I thing here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html (part about AlertDialog) is part of answer for me. When I will remake all my dialogs to AlerDialogs, I will post the code and answare on my question.